# HTML form or div for JQuery login?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, authentication

I want to create a login form on a single HTML page to display with JQuery (I am new to the technology).

I am wondering whether I should use a `<div>` and hide/display it, or use a `<form>` and hide/display it. The info will be sent to a servlet with Ajax.

If I use a `<div>`, what should I use as a substitute for `<input>` available in forms?

If I use a `<form>`, I believe I have to provide an action, which is annoying, since I use a single page. Is there a way to dodge this issue?

What is the recommended login method to use in this case, `<div>` or `<form>`?

Comment: I'm confused by what you mean by `<div>`

Comment: @John <div> can be used to fake a form by using the show and hide methods provided by JQuery. My googling tells me some people use this technique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `<form>` tag because it is semantically correct (the users are filling out a login **form**).

You can let `action=""` on the form, and prevent the form from trying to submit with the `onsubmit` property:

```
$("form#myForm").submit(function() {
    // do your ajax here

    return false; // prevents the default action
});
```

Answer (score 12):

> If I use a `<div>`, what should I use as a substitute for `<input>` available in forms?

It's perfectly legit to include `<input>` outside of `<form>`.

Having said that I would typically use a `<form>` so you can bind to its `onsubmit` event, instead of having to worry about people pressing Enter to submit the form and what events that generates (which is dependent on the browser and contents of the form). Better to mark a form up as a form and let the browser apply its normal form-like behaviours than to chase around trying to fake it.

Ideally, to do progressive enhancement properly, you should make the form work without JavaScript first, so there will actually be something useful at which to point `action`. Then add scripting/XMLHttpRequest on top. If you *must* have a form that only works with script, you could add it to the page from script, so that it's not present for non-JS users and they don't get confused trying to submit it.

Comment: Let's assume I make a prerequisite to have a Javascript enabled browser, <form> still has the benefit of onsubmit. OK. jtfairbank's suggestion seems interesting...

Comment: That is certainly the normal way you'd do a short-circuited form submission, yes. Same as with returning false on a link click.

Answer (score 9):

> I am wondering whether I should use a `<div>` and hide/display it, or use a `<form>` and hide/display it.

Use a form. [Build on things that work](http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/)

> If I use a `<div>`, what should I use as a substitute for `<input>` available in forms?

If you were to use a div then you would still use an input, but use a form.

> If I use a `<form>`, I believe I have to provide an action, which is annoying, since I use a single page.

Don't do that. Build on things that work.

Comment: @Quentin Are you saying I should use more than one page (=good practice)?

Comment: If JS is turned off, then any links should still work, any data collection you do should still work, and so on. That usually means you need multiple pages.

Answer (score 5):

It makes almost no difference - unless you're worried about [semantic content](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_HTML) (a `<form>` conveys it is meant for user input more clearly than a `<div>` would), [graceful degradation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fault-tolerant_system) (a `<form>` could still work without the JavaScript), [accessibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_accessibility) (which would probably require keeping graceful degradation in mind), [progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) or [unobtrusive javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

Comment: All of which are things you **should** care about.

Answer (score 1):

If you plan your app to be working for users without javascript enabled, use the `form` element which is a standard way of doing form submissions in HTML.

If it is only for ajax type postbacks, you can use a DIV as well. Of course, you will anyway need the `<input ../>` elements as these cannot be substituted by anything else.

One thing you get if using the `form` approach - you can then call the [`serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method of a form element to get all the field names + values in a string.

EDIT: no, actually the `serialize()` method can be used on any DOM element, so `form` has no advantages over `div`.